# access or show uploaded images that need authorization

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can successfully upload images by providing the `access_token` etc in the authorization header and it returns me a downloadURL. For uploading, I am doing as:

```
let res = await fetch(URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      },
      body: data
    })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
        return data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return error
      })
```

Now, I want that downloadURL to show it in html `<img />` tag as `

```
const downlaodURL = '/download/pid1/VwXLvSKQzp/Selection_006.png' 
<img src=`${downloadURL}`alt='image not found' />
```

but when I try to access the image, it is saying that you are not authenticated as: 
[image: unauthenticated image]

HOW TO ACCESS or SHOW IT IN THE HTML TAG?

I have many many images and I am rendering it in a loop as:

```
{images ? images.map((img, index) => (
                    <PinnedImage
                      key={index}
                      name={img.mediaName}
                      picture={img.downloadURL}
                      url={img.downloadURL}
                    />
                  )) : null}
```

In PinnedImage component:

```
<img className="imgHeight" src={this.props.picture} alt="image not found" />
```

How to show it? Should I use next authenticated Server for all images again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the AJAX call inside PinnedImage component for retrieving the image like below
PinnedImage.jsx

```
export class PinnedImage extends Component
{
 constructor(props)
 {
  super(props);
  this.state={image:''}
 }
componentWillMount()
{
const downlaodURL = '/download/pid1/VwXLvSKQzp/Selection_006.png' 
await fetch(downlaodURL , {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  }
 })
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({image:data});
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return error
  })

}

}
```

Now this.state.image holds actual image data (might be blob type) that can be referred in any React lifecycle method like render().

```
 <img className="imgHeight" src={this.state.image} alt="image not found" />
```

Comment: I will use HTTP `GET` request here to access the file and the `POST` as you have `POST` request in your answer. Right?